# How do I get all the children of a table without knowing their type, returned to a list?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a table called AppChartGroup, and then several child tables hanging off it, which hold the parameters for each type of chart.  So there could be a table called AppBarChart, and a table called AppPieChart, each with different parameters depending on the table.  Both linked to AppChartGroup by ChartGroupId.  The problem for me lies in the C# side of things.  I want to get a list of all the charts hanging off AppChartGroup, regardless of what type they are.  At the min, the only way I know of doing this is like this:

```
var testChartList = new List<object>();

foreach (var barChart in chartGroup.AppBarChart)
{
    testChartList.Add(barChart);
}

foreach (var pieChart in chartGroup.AppPieChart)
{
    testChartList.Add(pieChart);
}

foreach (var lineChart in chartGroup.AppLineChart)
{
    testChartList.Add(lineChart);
}
```

Surely there must be a more eloquent want of doing this?  Something along the lines of:

```
var testChartList = new List<object>();

foreach (var childChart in chartGroup.Children)
{
    testChartList.Add(childChart);
}
```

But suspect it's even easier than that, probably one line of linq does the job, unfortunately I'm not too good at linq.  Does anyone know a more efficient or better way of doing this?

**Edit**

Very basic model.

```
       AppChartGroup
       |     |     |
       |     |     |
BarChart PieChart LineChart
```

**Edit2**

Btw, I'm aware that what I'm asking may not be possible - I'm just asking if it *is* possible, but if you don't think it is, then don't hesitate to tell me so.

Comment: can you show the chartGroup model ?

Comment: what is type of children? Do they inherit some interface or are they all of same class?

Comment: Try something like this : List<Chart> charts = chartGroup.Cast<Chart>().Select(x => x).ToList();

Comment: Children are off different types.  They type isn't too relevant. I just want all children, regardless of type.  I will deal with their types once I have them all.

Comment: It depends on what `chartGroup` implements. What is the type or definition of `chartGroup`? Might help mentioning if this WinForm/WPF/ASP.NET/something else.

Comment: chartGroup is just an instance of AppChartGroup.  It's an AppChartGroup object.  This is an asp.net web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to use reflection . But this have a high chance of slowing down the system.

```
        var m = typeof (AppChartGroup).GetProperties().ToList();
        List<object> charts= new List<Object>;
        m.ForEach(prop =>
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(nameof(IEnumerable)) !=null)
            {
                var chart= prop.GetValue(chartGroup) as IEnumerable<object>;               
                charts.AddRange(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Seems like it should work, but it doesn't.  When it steps inside the 'if' statement, 'var chart' is null.  It doesn't get the list of charts of type 'prop'.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 .. have corrected the same ... it was due to variance issue

Comment: That doesn't work either.  It doesn't recognise "nameof".  Also that wasn't really the problem - it was getting inside the 'if' statement, it was at 'var chart' that the problem was - it wasn't populating 'var chart'.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 the nameof works only from c# 6 i believe , if you are using older framework you could use string "IEnumerable" . And  issue  where we get chart as null was due to casting  prop.GetValue(chartGroup) as List<Object>  instead of  IEnumerable<object>. This is because the covariance is not supporte by List<> class.

Comment: Thanks.  This is as close to an answer as I could get for what I was trying to do.  I'll accept this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to hold them up as `object` ? You can have a base class for the charts ( Like `ChartBase` )

If you want to get all charts from a single item :

```
var chartGroup = new ChartGroup();

List<ChartBase>testChartList = new List<ChartBase>();

testChartList.AddRange(chartGroup.AppBarChart);
testChartList.AddRange(chartGroup.AppPieChart);
testChartList.AddRange(chartGroup.AppLineChart);
```

Comment: Yes, I realise that I can go this route - there are a few ways of doing it.  But if I wanted them all just in a List<object>, what's the simplest way of getting all the children, without worrying about their types?  Maybe it can't be done?

Comment: It can be done. But it is not necessary in your situation. You can make your design better by following OOPS principles instead of holding stuffs in object. Hope this helps.

Comment: Did I answer your question ?

Comment: You didn't really answer my question.  I appreciate the response, and I know that there are better ways of doing it, I just want to do it a particular way, if it is possible.  So the correct answer should either provide with a way of doing what I want, or tell me it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

the below should do what you need without worrying about types.

```
var testChartList = chartGroup.AppBarCharts.Cast<object>().ToList();
testChartList.AddRange(chartGroup.AppPieCharts);
testChartList.AddRange(chartGroup.AppLineCharts);
```

Comment: But I still am worrying about types - I'd be specifying 'chartGroup.AppBarCharts'   I don't want to specify what type I'm getting, I just want all children of whatever type, regardless of type, and put into a generic list of objects.  Like I said, I'd like something like 'List<object> list = AppChartGroup.Children.toList();'

Comment: If you want to dynamically access properties on a class without calling the List property directly then you will have to use reflection. Can I ask why you don't want to access each list individually?  i.e. chartGroup.AppBarCharts. You've already made good savings using linq from the foreach loops. Which is only more readable... linq pretty much does the foreach under the hood anyway.

Comment: There's no real reason why I can't access each list individually, I just got curious as to whether it could be done all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Less efficient than `.AddRange`, but the LINQ version should be:

```
var testChartList = chartGroup.AppBarChart.Concat(chartGroup.AppPieChart)
                                          .Concat(chartGroup.AppLineChart).ToList();
```

Depending on what `chartGroup.Children` implements, this might work:

```
var testChartList = chartGroup.Children.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: chartGroup.Children doesn't exist.  I was using that as an example of what I want to be able to do.